# JavaSript узнать является ли день выходным днем?

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли в Javascript узнать является ли дата 04.02.2021 выходным днем суббота или воскресенье?

Comment: под выходным днем вы понимаете субботу и воскресенье, или все же нерабочий день по производственному календарю в какой-то определнной стране мира?

Comment: В данном случае нужно понять выходной день суббота или воскресенье

Comment: пожалуйста, дополните этой информацией вопрос ([edit]).

Comment: В каком формате подаётся дата на вход программе? Строка, которую нужно распарсить?

Comment: В вопросе я указал 04.02.2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для определения номера дня в неделе есть метод [`.getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Данный метод возвращает значение от 0 до 6, соответствующее номеру конкретного дня.

Начиная с 0 - воскресенье, заканчивая 6 - суббота.

Исходя из этого, достаточно привести строку к дате, вызвать данный метод и проверить вернет ли метод 6 или 0.

```js
console.log(checkDate('06.02.2021'));
console.log(checkDate('04.02.2021'));

function checkDate(dateStr) {
  const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split('.');

  const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

  return (date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6);
}
```